# Parsing out substrings matching a given pattern from a complex string

Tags: python, string, parsing, split, python-re

I'm working on a script that can do a few quick calculations that I usually do by hand. The string below varies because it is an item description but the format comes in two types typically. I need a way of parsing out the `xMM` from the rest of the script because it's what I need to the calculations and can get it from there. I've tried using partition and some different `.split()` combinations but I'm not sure that I'm understanding the finer inner workings on how they function.

The bold numbers vary but the info I'm trying to parse will always be `(*)*MM`. If that helps.

```
test1 = 'TYP4,(g)DV, 6/8", 13.5MM-(g)6MM FVC/.060PVB/(g)6MM FVC Locked C3, Item Stat, Special Op'

test2 = 'TYP5,(x)DC, 1/2", (x)6MM CDS, Check C3'


print(test1.split("MM",1))
print(test2.split("MM",1))

char1 = ')'
char2 = 'MM'

print(test[test.find(char1)+1 : test.find(char2)])
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit adding some of my attempts to get the goal of [6MM,6MM] or [6,6]. Not listed due to frustrated deleting is attempts to .split on the ')' and few other small combinations. Maybe I'm overthinking this because it appears that this is not a complex problem. I'm not sure if changing the title will affect anything.

Comment: You're trying to get ['6MM', '6MM'] from test1 and ['6MM'] from test2? Or [6,6] and [6]? Or something else?

Comment: kindly, give a short code of your trial illustrating the target output.

Comment: You tagged your question with `re`, so presumably you did some research about them. This is a very simple regex to write. What did you try using regular expressions, and why did that attempt not work?

Comment: @jarmod , either versions will work, my goal is [6,6] but I believe I can correct [6MM.6MM] from there.

Comment: @Nour-AllahHussein I'll edit the post to add some examples but I've been scrapping them or copying over them as they fail (not a standard practice I've just been on and off again trying to solve this for a few weeks).

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I tried using a few variations of .split() and .partition() but I can't isolate the specifics I want. I can get some of the parts isolated but I don't really comprehend how to remove the excess data. I'm very new to this portion of programming and have been working around it until I had no choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regex

```
import re
s1 = 'TYP4,(g)DV, 6/8", 13.5MM-(g)6MM FVC/.060PVB/(g)6MM FVC Locked C3, Item Stat, Special Op'
m = re.findall('\(*\)(\d+MM)', s1)
```

Then do something with `m`

The matched groups in the given example are:

- Match 1 Full match   28-32   )6MM
- Group 1. 29-32   6MM
- Match 2 Full match   47-51   )6MM
- Group 1. 48-51   6MM

Comment: Did you mean `\(.*\)(\d+MM)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the bottom portion is but this does work perfectly for isolating my data. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Omnishroom - the bottom part is just showing the match groups - sorry if it confused!

Answer (score 0):

in xMM x could be an integer or a float, below code catches both the values.

```
import re
p = re.compile("\d+\.\d+MM|\d+MM")
p.findall('TYP4,(g)DV, 6/8", 13.5MM-(g)6MM FVC/.060PVB/(g)6MM FVC Locked C3, Item Stat, Special Op')

output: ['13.5MM', '6MM', '6MM']
```

hope that helps and if you want to write your own regular expressions, start from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regular-expression-python-examples-set-1/) to give it a try.

Note: The accepted answer is failing to catch `13.5MM` from the first string in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry if the post wasn't clear, but I was only trying to catch the 6MM the float number is a combination of the two 6MM & the PVB which is inconsequential for my purposes. Thank you for providing another example, it is much appreciated.

Comment: @Omnishroom, well, I didn't get that from the initial question. Anyway if you find it useful you can upvote. thanks